# Select image inside svg using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am working on a small script where I should make some edits on images inside SVG using jquery.
This is my svg code :

```
    <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         version="1.1"
         width="800"
         height="420"
         id="svg">
     <image class="draggable" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://letscode.ghost.io/content/images/2015/09/stackoverflow.png" width="800" heigqht="420" id="yassin" >

</image> 
</svg>
```

I want to select the image by it's id Yassin and then edit the attribute width.
PS. I used the getelementbyID and the jquery selector but it doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your image's width attribute i.e. heigqht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery:

```
 var img = $('#yassin');
```

[jQuery Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2rgzx9w9/)

pure javascript:

```
 var img = document.getElementById('yassin');
```

The [Pure Javascript Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j4n7se0L/)

To change the Width as you mentioned in comments:

```
$('#yassin').attr('width', 500); //this way you can change any attribute
```

or just:

```
$('#yassin').width(500); //this is simply for setting the width value
```

Comment: The problem is making the edits and adding attributes . I want to edit the width value using js or jquery.

Comment: It works like a charm :) please allow me 4 minutes to accept your answer as long as i just accepted another one so i should wait. Thank you so much